# How to use a column value in one of the select statement in the join in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, inner-join

I'm updating `sitename` as below. But then I need to utilize the `levelindex` from `a` in another query which is getting joined with the first query.

```
update billofquantity_temp a
    set sitename = b.boqitemname 
from (
 select a.* from
 (
 select levelindex,productno,boqitemid,boqitemname,fileid from billofquantity_temp
                where productno ='' and levelindex !='' //first query
 ) a
    join 
 (
 select distinct substring(levelindex,1,length(a.levelindex) lblindex from billofquantity_temp
               where boqitemid !='' and levelindex !='' 
               and length(levelindex) > 2
 ) b    on a.levelindex=b.lblindex // second query 
) b
where a.levelindex=b.levelindex;
```

I need to use the a.levelindex in second query to get the substrings of the it's length. But this throws error `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"`

Is there any other way to use the column from query 1 in 2 while joining them?

> Update:
> Based on kims answer, I could get the selection done but there is error  `syntax error at c.a.levelindex`. There error is thrown even with `c.levelindex`.
> A slight modification to the query made no errors but the intened update doesn't happen. Instead only one particular values is updated. Below is the updated query to remove errors

```
 update billofquantity_temp d
 set sitename = c.boqitemname
 from (
      select *  from (
            select levelindex, boqitemname from billofquantity_temp
            where productno = '' and levelindex != '' -- first query
                     ) a
                join (
            select distinct levelindex lblindex from billofquantity_temp
            where boqitemid != '' and levelindex != '' and length(levelindex) > 2   ) b
on a.levelindex = substring(b.lblindex, 1, length(a.levelindex)) -- second query
      ) c 
       where d.levelindex = c.lblindex;
```

Comment: maybe try using four different identifiers instead of `a` twice and `b` twice

Answer (score 1):

Move the computation of `lblindex` outside the sub-select to the `on` clause:

```
update billofquantity_temp d
set sitename = c.boqitemname
from (
    select *
    from (
        select levelindex, boqitemname
        from billofquantity_temp
        where productno = '' and levelindex != '' -- first query
    ) a
    join (
        select distinct levelindex
        from billofquantity_temp
        where boqitemid != '' and levelindex != '' and length(levelindex) > 2     
    ) b
    on a.levelindex = substring(b.levelindex, 1, length(a.levelindex)) -- second query
) c 
where d.levelindex = c.a.levelindex
;
```

I've also used `c` and `d` to avoid confusion from using `a` and `b` twice, added a missing `)`, and removed unused fields from `select`.

Comment: It throws ```Column reference level index is ambiguous``` at the ```c.levelindex```

Comment: Try `c.a.levelindex`.